# Capturar Valor Atributo Id XML

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

A través de un archivo PHP, capturo los valores de un archivo XML.
El valor que no consigo capturar es el del atributo ID de una de las etiquetas.
El provado diversas opciones y todos me dan error.
Les paso el codigo:

```
<?php
$xml = simplexml_load_file("a.xml") or die ("a.xml");

echo $xml->coord->coordi[0]->latitude . "<br>";
echo $xml->coord->coordi[0]->longitude . "<br>";
echo $xml->coord->coord[0]->altitude . "<br>";

echo "<br>";

$xml = simplexml_load_file("b.xml") or die ("Error de carrega arxiu b.xml");
echo $xml->coord->coordi[0]->latitude . "<br>";
echo $xml->coord->coordi[0]->longitude . "<br>";
echo $xml->coord->coordi[0]->altitude . "<br>";

echo "<br>";

$xml = simplexml_load_file("c.xml") or die ("Error de carrega arxiu c.xml");
echo $xml->coord->coordi[0]->latitude . "<br>";
echo $xml->coord->coordi[0]->longitude . "<br>";
echo $xml->coord->coordi[0]->altitude . "<br>";

echo "<br>";

$xml = simplexml_load_file("d.xml") or die ("Error de carrega arxiu d.xml");
echo $xml->coord->coordi[0]->latitude . "<br>";
echo $xml->coord->coordi[0]->longitude . "<br>";
echo $xml->coord->coordi[0]->altitude . "<br>";
```

?
Hay la etiqueta G que tiene el atributo ID="2", es este valor el que no consigo recuperar. ¿ Alguien se le ocurre como hacerlo ?
Gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Con la siguiente instrucción puedo sacar el valor del atributo ID.
echo $xml->attributes() . "
";
Gracias.